# Invoke an EJB from a Quartz job

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, quartz-scheduler

I have a Java EE application that runs on Wildfly and I'd like to integrate it with the Quartz Scheduler. This is how I envision to invoke an EJB from a Quartz job (since I don't know the name of the EJB class at compile time, I use a lookup):

```
public class MyJob implements Job {

    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext arg0) throws JobExecutionException {        

        InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
        MyInterface bean = null;
        try {
            String beanClassName  = getItFromSomewhere();
            bean = (MyInterface) ic.lookup("java:module/" + beanClassName );
        } 
        catch (NamingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        bean.myMethod();
     }
}
```

Is this approach correct? The container wouldn't know about the Quartz job when 
 it's initiated, is that an issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imho a cleaner alternative is passing the `EJB` instance via the `Job`'s `JobExecutionContext`

When preparing the `Job`

```
final JobDataMap jobDataMap = new JobDataMap();
jobDataMap.put(MY_INTERFACE, myInterface);

final Job myJob =
    JobBuilder.newJob(MyJob.class)
              .setJobData(jobDataMap)
              .build();
```

Inside `Job#execute`

```
final JobDataMap jobDataMap = context.getJobDetail().getJobDataMap();
final MyInterface myInterface = (MyInterface) jobDataMap.get(MY_INTERFACE);
```

---

A Quartz `Job` implementation shouldn't be aware at all of the JavaEE container in which it is operating. This will will ease the process of updating your code/architecture in the long term.
Also, your `Job` should only care about its only duty, not about getting the required dependencies.
Think about the `JobDataMap` as a strange kind of *Dependency Injection*.

Comment: How do I invoke the bean after I get the interface from `JobDataMap` ?

Comment: @ps0604 like any other normal object. It's just an instance.

Comment: In your example I don't see a reference to `MyBean`, so where's the instance?

Comment: @ps0604 you mean MyInterface. It is inserted in the job map when constructing the job. See above

Comment: No, I mean `MyBean`, that implements `MyInterface`. In the job, I need to run a method of `MyBean`. I used `MyInterface` because at compilation time I don't know the name of the bean class.

Comment: @ps0604 your bean instance is still retrieved using InitialContext, but not inside the Job. Instead when building the Job definition.

Comment: I don't see how you can get a reference to `MyBean`, can you add it to your example? thanks.

Comment: @ps0604 yes, after lunch I'll edit it. Anyway, in the same way you're doing it now. Just not inside the Job

Comment: Thanks, just consider that since the name of the class is not known at compilation time, it is not known when `JobBuilder` creates the job either. It is only known when the job is run.

Comment: @ps0604 but I see the job uses an hard-coded interface, and an hard-coded jndi name.

Comment: It's just an example, I say in the question that the name of the bean is not known at compilation time. But you're right, it should be a variable and not an explicit name (see now).

Comment: @ps0604 well, just call `getItFromSomewhere` at construction point. Or does that method accept a parameter that is known only inside the job? Maybe post the real one so I can give you an accurate answer.

Comment: yes, the method would accept a parameter, and depending on the parameter it knows the name of the bean to invoke. Sorry if the question is not completely clear.

Comment: @ps0604 and how is that parameter retrieved? This is important to understand if the retrieval can be done outside the job context, or in other ways

Comment: The beans will be created dynamically, that's why the names are not known at compilation time. In addition, when a job is scheduled it will pass a code as a parameter. The job, when it starts, it will take this code and derive the bean class name.

Comment: @ps0604 well if you have the code at job definition  time why don't you use it to retrieve the bean immediately? Instead of waiting for the job to retrieve it

Comment: Yes, that will work. the name of the class is not known when the code is compiled, but it is known when the job is scheduled. When the job is defined it is not known.

Comment: @ps0604 then you can move the retrieval of the Bean instance at job scheduling time, and then pass that instance via JobDataMap, as I've shown above

Comment: @ps0604 awesome ;)

Comment: Please look [here](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/2.3.1-SNAPSHOT/best-practices.html#only-store-primitive-data-types-including-strings-in-the-jobdatamap) where Quartz says to only store primitives and strings in `JobDataMap`. Thougths?

Comment: @ps0604 this is **potentially** valid if your application is *distributed* across multiple JVMs. Even then, if your class implements `Serializable` correctly, you won't have any problem.

Comment: When I try to apply this solution the trigger goes to ERROR state. I am trying to store a simple @Stateless bean without any body just for debug reason, that EJB  implements Serializable and has none other annotation. I found that the problem raises when storing the EJB in jobDataMap. Any hint will be very helpfull...

Comment: @IliasStavrakis could you use pastebin to show the error stacktrace?

Comment: @LppEdd When the object that I am trying to store was injected with @Inject no stack trace is printed in logs of Weblogic but when I inject it's interface with `@EJB` and do the same store on injected interface instance I get the following : org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: Couldn't store job: Unable to serialize JobDataMap for insertion into database because the value of property 'process' is not serializable: NotificationMailProcess_b6aicg_NotificationMailProcessIntImpl , But the EJB is a dummy @Stateless empty EJB that implements serializable and has no code

Comment: What happens when you restart the server after having scheduled the Job? Who takes care of instantiating an EJB object and injecting  it in MyJob?

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer provided by the Quart'z developers on GitHub:

https://github.com/quartz-scheduler/quartz/blob/master/quartz-jobs/src/main/java/org/quartz/jobs/ee/ejb/EJBInvokerJob.java

To summarize: Your approach is right, in  your MyJob class you correctly create an InitialContext() to search of the EJB instance you would like to invoke.
You cannot put an instance of the EJB in the JobContext, as suggested by the previous answer, because in case there is a server restart between the scheduling of the Job and its invocation, you have no guarantee that an instance of the EJB you want will be "injected" in the JobContext.